# threejs - creating 3d perspective for a line

Tags: three.js

I'm working on an app where I visualize ATV trails in a 3d perspective (NAIP imagery draped over elevation data).  I am using three.js for the rendering engine.[image]

In the above image, the white line you see is just a THREE.Line instance, where I convert a trails gps coordinates into threejs coordinates.  I'd like to add more of 3d perspective to this line.  I tried implementing a THREE.TubeGeometry where the path was a THREE.CatmullRomCurve3 using the same Vector3 points as how I built the line you see in the image above.  That did not produce a desirable result...
[image]

From the many, many THREE examples I have looked at, I really think an extruded geometry would achieve the look I am after...  But I cant for the life of me figure out how to extrude a geometry for the line.  Any suggestions/thoughts?

**UPDATE 1:**
Here is my desired look (same trail - no imagery).  This image was produced in QGIS using the Q2Threejs plugin
[image]

**UPDATE 2:**  Here is a code of how I have attempted to create a tubegeometry.  Maybe I am messing something up in there...

```
// trailVectors are an array of Vector3 - same as ones used to create line
var trailCurve = new THREE.CatmullRomCurve3(trailVectors);
var tubeGeometry = new THREE.TubeGeometry(trailCurve,80,1,15,false);
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color:0x00ff00});
var tubeMesh = new THREE.Mesh(tubeGeometry,material);
var wireframeMaterial = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({color:0xffffff,lineWidth:2});
var wireframe = new THREE.Mesh(tubeGeometry,wireframeMaterial);
tubeMesh.add(wireframe);
scene.add(tubeMesh);
```

**UPDATE 3**
THREE.TubeGeometry(trailCurve,80,4,2,false) per mzartman request
[image]

Comment: are you trying to draw a thick line over the path?

Comment: Can you perhaps add some reference shots / photos / drawings from what your desired look is? I'm not so sure how to interpret "adding more 3d perspective to a line". Assuming you get TubeGeometry to work, do you -want- a tube-like look for your trails?

(Also, maybe it's just me, but I feel you've got a really nice visualisation thing going with that simple line rendering)

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I've edited my post adding a picture of desired look.

Answer (score 2):

I think that you should be able to achieve what you want with a TubeGeometry.  I think the big thing is that your example (from the picture shown) has more than 2 radius segments.  That gives it the tubular shape and makes it look sort of like a blob.  If you set the radial segment count to 2 (as it's shown below) then I think it would look a lot better.

```
    tubeGeometry = new THREE.TubeBufferGeometry( 

     [YOUR_PATH_HERE], 
     params.extrusionSegments,   // <--- Edit this for higher resolution on the spline
     3,                          // <--- This defines the height
     2,                          // <--- This 2 keeps 2D (i.e. not a tube!!!!)
     true );

     var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
     var wireframe = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, wireframeMaterial );

     mesh.add( wireframe );
     scene.add( mesh );
```

**Update:**

I think that you might do better with a material that shows some shadow like the MeshPhong.  Also, to do the wireframe you want to add it as an option in the material initialization.  Give it a show with the following:

```
var tubeGeometry = new THREE.TubeGeometry(curve,80,1,2,false);
var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color:0x00ff00, wireframe: true});
var tubeMesh = new THREE.Mesh(tubeGeometry,material);
scene.add(tubeMesh);
```

Comment: Also, giving it a wireframe may help to provide some structure to the material.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  When I look at a sample TubeGeometry (https://threejs.org/docs/#api/geometries/TubeGeometry) - you can play with the segments, radius, and radialSegments properties.  I have tried all different combinations, but my tubegeometry never looks anything close to the tubegeometry on that page...  I've added a code snippet to my original post - maybe I am messing up something there.

Comment: I see what you're going for now.  If you to make a box that might be harder, but you can turn a tube into what is basically a plane if you change the radial segments.

`var tubeGeometry = new THREE.TubeGeometry(trailCurve,80,4,2,false);` Can you show the output when you change that?

Comment: Thanks again for your help.  I've attached an image with THREE.TubeGeometry(trailCurve,80,4,2,false) per your request.;

Comment: Updated my original answer.  Maybe try again with that and see if you like the results.  If you don't like the look of that, it might be a good idea to get some lights and take away the wireframe, and play around with how it looks then.  Beyond this the best thing I can think of is to do math between points and just do a box geometry, but that would take a little more work.  I think that the tube geometry should be good enough for what you're trying to do though.